# How do I abstract private functions into a utility library?

Tags: elixir

Say I have a bunch of code like below :

```
def dirs(path, regex_dir \\ ".+") do
  path
  |> normalize_path
  |> do_dirs([], regex_dir)
end

# list of bitstrings
defp normalize_path([path | rest]) when is_bitstring(path) do
  [path | normalize_path(rest)]
end

# list of character lists
defp normalize_path([path | rest]) when is_list(path) do
  [to_string(path) | normalize_path(rest)]
end

defp normalize_path([]) do
  []
end

# bitstring
defp normalize_path(path) when is_bitstring(path) do
  [path]
end

# character list
defp normalize_path(path) when is_list(path) do
  [to_string(path)]
end
```

I want to use the normalize_path in another part of the code, what's the best way to abstract away the normalize_path function into a utility module or library ? I still want to maintain the function to only be used internally and not available as a public function.

Comment: Having something in a utility module/library but having it hidden seems like two opposing goals.

Answer (score 6):

Probably your best shot is abstracting those functions in a separate module and hide it in the documentation with `@moduledoc false`. Those functions won't be *private* and will still be accessible to users of your library, but by not documenting them you're flagging them as not part of the library's API.

```
defmodule Helpers do
  @moduledoc false

  @doc """
  You can still provide per-function docs for documenting how the code works;
  these docs won't be public anyways since `@moduledoc false` hides them.
  """
  def helper(...), do: ...
end
```

Comment: +1. This is exactly the pattern I use when extracting complex private functions to other modules to help testing.

Comment: @JoséValim I must have taken that from somewhere, right? :)